# Error in Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, dynamic, dynamic-sql

I Have Created the following SP to generate the Update Statements and it uses the table 
Col.TMap.T_Mp and the data in the table looks like:

```
ID  M_Type  ID_F     SF1      SF2
1   Acc     ACC_ID   AC_ID    NULL
1   STA     STA_ID   ST_ID    NULL
1   CHa     Cha_ID   CH_ID    NULL



CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.dtmap(
@ID INT
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SchemaName SYSNAME
DECLARE @TableName SYSNAME
DECLARE @DatabaseName SYSNAME
DECLARE @M_Type SYSNAME
DECLARE @SF1 VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @SF2 VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @ID_F VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @BR CHAR(2)
SET @BR = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)


DECLARE tickmapcur CURSOR FOR SELECT M_Type,ID_F,SF1,SF2
                              FROM Col.TMap.T_Mp
                              WHERE   [_ID] = @ID 



SELECT  @SchemaName = Source_Schema ,
        @TableName = Source_Table ,
        @DatabaseName = Source_Database
FROM    Manserv.dbo.S_Ds
WHERE   ID = @ID



OPEN   tickmapcur  

FETCH NEXT FROM tickmapcur INTO @M_Type,@ID_F,@SF1,@SF2

while @@fetch_status = 0

BEGIN


SET @SQL = 'SELECT SO1,
                   SO2,
                   ID
INTO ' + @M_Type + '_mtemp' + @BR + 'FROM ' + @M_Type + @BR
    + 'WHERE [ID] = ' + CAST(@ID AS NVARCHAR(10)) + @BR+ @BR


SET @SQL = @SQL + 'UPDATE  mt ' + @BR + 'SET ' + @ID_F+ ' = ac.' + @ID_F
    + @BR + 'FROM ' + @DatabaseName + '.' + @SchemaName + '.' + @TableName + ' t' + @BR 
    + 'LEFT OUTER JOIN '+ @M_Type + '_mtemp' 
    +' mtemp ON mtemp.ID = ' +  CAST(@ID AS NVARCHAR(10)) + @BR 
     + 'INNER JOIN ' + @M_Type + ' ac ON t.' + @SF1
    + COALESCE(mtemp.SO1, '') + ' SV1'
    + CASE WHEN @SF2 is NULL THEN '' ELSE COALESCE(@SF2, '')
    + COALESCE(mtemp.SO2, '') + ' SV2' END
    + 'AND ac.[ID] = ' + CAST(@ID AS NVARCHAR(10))
    + @BR + 'INNER JOIN ' + @DatabaseName + '.' + @SchemaName + '.'
    + @TableName + '_Dmtemp mt' + @BR
    + 'ON mt.[SRID] = t.[RID]  ' + @BR
    +@BR

FETCH NEXT FROM tickmapcur INTO @M_Type,@ID_F,@SF1,@SF2

PRINT ( @SQL )
END 

CLOSE tickmapcur
DEALLOCATE tickmapcur

END
```

I get the following message:

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure dtmap, Line 57
The multi-part identifier "mtemp.SO1" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure  dtmap, Line 57
The multi-part identifier "mtemp.SO1" could not be bound.
```

The output should be like this:

```
SELECT SO1,
       SO2,
       ID
INTO  ACC_Mtemp
FROM ACC
WHERE [ID] = @ID



UPDATE  mt 
SET ACC_ID = ac.ACC_ID
FROM Ms.AT.AT_CRAW t
LEFT OUTER JOIN ACC_Mtemp mtemp ON
mtemp.ID = @ID
INNER JOIN Acc ac ON t.AC_ID=SV1
AND ac.ID = 1
INNER JOIN Ms.AT.AT_CRAW_Dmtemp mt  mt
ON mt.[SRID] = t.[RID]

SELECT SO1,
       SO2,
       ID
INTO  STA_Mtemp
FROM STA
WHERE [ID] = @ID



UPDATE  mt 
SET STA_ID = ac.STA_ID
FROM Ms.AT.AT_CRAW t
LEFT OUTER JOIN STA_Mtemp mtemp ON
mtemp.ID = @ID
INNER JOIN STA ac ON t.ST_ID=SV1
AND ac.ID = 1
INNER JOIN Ms.AT.AT_CRAW_Dmtemp mt  mt
ON mt.[SRID] = t.[RID]


SELECT SO1,
       SO2,
       ID
INTO  CHa_Mtemp
FROM CHa
WHERE [ID] = @ID



UPDATE  mt 
SET CHa_ID = ac.CHa_ID
FROM Ms.AT.AT_CRAW t
LEFT OUTER JOIN CHa_Mtemp mtemp ON
mtemp.ID = @ID
INNER JOIN CHa ac ON t.CH_ID=SV1
AND ac.ID = 1
INNER JOIN Ms.AT.AT_CRAW_Dmtemp mt  mt
ON mt.[SRID] = t.[RID]
```

Comment: Can you show us the output of that `PRINT ( @SQL )`?

Comment: @Joe I have added the Output to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are building the query incorrectly.  ALL of the SQL parts need to be in quotes.  The only thing outside of them should be the variables you are passing in.

Comment: @Chris I know the problem is the temp table is created dynamically where as COALESCE(mtemp.SO1, '') is normal SQL and it is trying to get that column value from that temp table which is created dynamically. But I dont know how to fix it

Comment: @Sam: No, the problem is that you have intermixed regular SQL (COALESCE(mtemp.SO1, '') OUTSIDE of your string concatenation.  The only thing outside of quotes should be the variables you are appending.

Comment: @Chris I cannot use them in the string since mtemp.SO1 and mtemp.SO2 have the values like '=' ,'Like' and I will be using them in the join so I cannot put them in the string

Comment: @Sam - to be more specific, the problem is you are approaching this problem in a way that **WILL NOT EVER WORK.**  You cannot build a dynamic string based on results from inside the string.  You could potentially build a dynamic query to build another nested dynamic query but it's a pretty bad idea.

Comment: @Sam - Rethink your process, probably.  Maybe make a new post looking for suggestions, with your data structure, sample data, and what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @JNK Thank you so much I have just posted a new post with data structure and sample data

Comment: @JNK Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the `mtemp` alias while you are creating the string. I suppose that you want to use it in the query instead:

```
+ ' COALESCE(mtemp.SO1, '''') SV1'
```

Same for `mtemp.SO2` two lines down.

Comment: I know the problem is the temp table is created dynamically where as COALESCE(mtemp.SO1, '') is normal SQL and it is trying to get that column value from that temp table which is created dynamically. But I dont know how to fix it

Comment: @Sam: In that case you have to create the temp table before you can create the second part of the dynamic query, so your dynamic query would have to create a dynamic query.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your missing a single quote before the `COALESCE(mtemp.SO1, '')` section.

Comment: I know the problem is the temp table is created dynamically where as COALESCE(mtemp.SO1, '') is normal SQL and it is trying to get that column value from that temp table which is created dynamically. But I dont know how to fix it