# How to Build Dynamic SQl for this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I have to create a Procedure with dynamic SQL and generate the Update Statements.

I have tables

Col.TMap.T_Mp

```
 ID   M_Type  ID_F     SF1      SF2
  1   Acc     ACC_ID   AC_ID    NULL
  1   STA     STA_ID   ST_ID    NULL
  1   CHa     Cha_ID   CH_ID    NULL
```

ACC

```
ID    AC_ID   SV1   SV2     SO1    SO2
1     12      6     NULL    =      NULL
```

STA

```
ID     STA_ID      SV1     SV2      SO1    SO2
1      1           Open    NULL     =      NULL
1      2           CLosed  NULL     =      NULL
```

CHa

```
ID    CHa_ID    SV1    SV2    SO1    SO2
1     1         PH     NULL   =      NULL
1     2         EM     NULL   =      NULL
```

I need to update Ms.AT.AT_CRAW_Dmtemp table with ACC_ID,STA_ID and CHA_ID from the above tables:

The out put should be:

```
UPDATE  mt 
SET ACC_ID = ac.ACC_ID
FROM Ms.AT.AT_CRAW t
INNER JOIN Acc ac ON t.AC_ID=SV1
AND ac.ID = 1
INNER JOIN Ms.AT.AT_CRAW_Dmtemp mt 
ON mt.[SRID] = t.[RID]



UPDATE  mt 
SET STA_ID = ac.STA_ID
FROM Ms.AT.AT_CRAW t
INNER JOIN STA ac ON t.ST_ID=SV1
AND ac.ID = 1
INNER JOIN Ms.AT.AT_CRAW_Dmtemp mt 
ON mt.[SRID] = t.[RID]



UPDATE  mt 
SET CHa_ID = ac.CHa_ID
FROM Ms.AT.AT_CRAW t
INNER JOIN CHa ac ON t.CH_ID=SV1
AND ac.ID = 1
INNER JOIN Ms.AT.AT_CRAW_Dmtemp mt  
ON mt.[SRID] = t.[RID]
```

So can anyone suggest me on how to do this?

Comment: @Sam - after seeing this again, you actually have a data modelling problem at the root.  It's a very bad idea to store table names in fields in another table for something like this.

Comment: @JNK It was designed by someother people and unfortunately I cannot change it

Comment: @Sam - it may be worthwhile to lobby management to let you fix it instead of wasting so much time designing poorly-performing work arounds for this.

Comment: @JNK what changes should I make to work this?

Comment: @Sam - break your types out into different tables, for one.  that would eliminate the dynamic join condition which is causing all the grief.  For a short term fix you could make a view for each type.

Comment: @JNK can you tell me how should I use the views to fix this?

Comment: @SAM - make a view with a definition like `SELECT * FROM Col.Tmap.t_mp WHERE m_Type = 'Acc'` Then you can run your dynamic SQL on that view and KNOW it will join to the `ACC` table instead of needing to query that field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
'UPDATE  mt
SET ' + ID_F + ' = ac.' + ID_F + '
FROM Ms.AT.AT_CRAW t
INNER JOIN ' + M_Type + ' ac ON t.' + SF1 + '=SV1
AND ac.ID = 1
INNER JOIN Ms.AT.AT_CRAW_Dmtemp mt 
ON mt.[SRID] = t.[RID]' as SQL
from Col.TMap.T_Mp
```

Comment: @Amit the values of SO1 and SO2 from three tables will not be same always and I cannot hardcore tha value of SO1 to be  '=' because the values might eb changing depending on the table

Comment: How are Col.TMap.T_Mp and other table related i.e. how to get the value of SO1?

Comment: @Amit The column M_Type in the Col.TMap.T_Mp table stores the names of the tables where the SO1 values is stored.

Comment: What about the multiple rows e.g. table STA and CHA have multiple rows.

Comment: @Amit it will go through all the records

Comment: So in the example given above it would generate 5 UPDATE statements?

Comment: @Amit no It will generate 3 update statements. The two tables STA and CHA have two rows each but if you observe the join the column name from the Ms.AT.AT_CRAW  table is used and the column value from the STA and CHA are used. For Ex: In the table Ms.AT.AT_CRAW the values of ST_ID will be 'Open' and 'Closed' and if you observe the value of SV1 in STA is also 'Open' and 'Closed'

Comment: I guess I am not getting the logic then. Please explain the logic to generate the UPDATE statements. Put the logic in the original question so that anyone can take a look quickly. Make sure to explain the relationship as well. Is the number of UPDATE statements equal to number of rows in table T_Mp?

Comment: @Amit Ya The number of UPDATE statements are equal to the number of rows in table T_Mp

Comment: Then how does the SO1 column come into the picture? If one row in STA had = and another one had > how would an UPDATE statement look like? If the SO1 is always same for a given table, that column should be moved to table Col.TMap.T_M.

Comment: @AMit you can look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206265/error-in-dynamic-sql

Comment: This is not addressed in that post also. Could SO1 be different within any given table (say STA)?

Comment: @Amit Ya the SO1 can be different within given table. It may change depending on ID in the table

Comment: So how would the number of UPDATE statements be equal to the number of row in Col.TMap.T_M? For example in the original post both rows in STA have SO1 as = and so the number of UPDATE statements are 3. What if one of the row in STA had SO1 as = and another as !=. How many UPDATE statements would then be needed?

Comment: @amit - I would upvote you twice for effort in dealing with this particular issue :)

Comment: @JNK, thanks. Unfortunately, I still don't understand the requirements :)

Comment: @amit - neither does he so it all balances out

Comment: @Amit I am sorry I really appreciate all your help on this. The number of update statments depend on ID column in Col.TMap.T_M. For Ex: the number of rows for ID 1 are three so the update statements will also be three and the SO1 will have same value for the ID1 and if the table Col.TMap.T_M has 6 rows 3 with ID 1 and 3 with ID 2 then we will get 6 update statements. and the SO1 can be different for ID 1 and ID 2.